# Replace carriage return for lines not containing specific string by Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text line following

```
Procedure Gato
Do task1
    If early Then come back
    turn 2
End Procedure
Schedule Balo
    If late Then go to home
    turn 2
End Schedule'
```

The result I need is

```
Procedure Gato: Do task1: If early Then come back
    turn 2: End Procedure
Schedule Balo: If late Then go to home
    turn 2: End Schedule'
```

I used pattern `\(?!\n.*(\b(Procedure |Schedule |Then )).*)\n\` to replace all carriage return not containing "Procedure" or "Schedule" or "Then" before. However it works well for only "Procedure" and "Schedule" not including "Then".
How to get the exact result as I need? Glad to receive some advice.

Comment: The pattern I used is /(?!\n.*(\b(Procedure |Schedule |Then )).*)\n/g.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern will do the job:

```
(^(?:(?!Then)(?! Procedure)(?! Schedule).)*)(\n\s*)
```

Its basically capturing the lines that don't have the words on the lookAheads and replacing `\n\s*` with the space(`\s*` mostly for next line tabs). I captured the group with the rest of the line also so the replacement must be `$1:`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fL6lO9/1)

Comment: Thank for your comment. Base on your pattern, I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
|Then
```

to:

```
|.*Then
```

or replace the `.*` with a more restrictive regex.  For example:

```
/(?!\n.*(\b(Procedure |Schedule |.*?Then )).*)\n/g
```

Comment: /(?!\n.*(\b(Procedure |Schedule |.*?Then )).*)\n/g